# Kanna removes nodes when parsing HTML

Tags: html, swift, kanna

I'm using Kanna to traverse a HTML of a website looking for `<script type="application:ld+json">`.

```
    func scrapeRecipe(from data: Data) {
        
        let html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        
        do {
            let document = try HTML(html: html!, encoding: .utf8)
            let script = document.xpath("//script[@type='application/ld+json']//text()")
            
            for recipeJSON in script {
                let data = recipeJSON.text?.data(using: .utf8)
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                
                
             //Handling fetched data here   
                
            }
            
        } catch {
            //Handle Error
        }
    }
```

The issue I am coming across, that on some websites, the `let document = try HTML(html: html!, encoding: .utf8)` step somehow removes the node notations, but doesn't on others.

The case in point: the original HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large, index, follow, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1'/>

    <script>
    (function(w, d) {
        w.adthrive = w.adthrive || {};
        w.adthrive.cmd = w.adthrive.cmd || [];
        w.adthrive.plugin = 'adthrive-ads-1.0.43';
        w.adthrive.host = 'ads.adthrive.com';

        var s = d.createElement('script');
        s.async = true;
        s.referrerpolicy = 'no-referrer-when-downgrade';
        s.src = 'https://' + w.adthrive.host + '/sites/55cb7e3b4bc841bd0c4ea577/ads.min.js?referrer=' + w.encodeURIComponent(w.location.href);
        var n = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n);
    })(window, document);
    </script>

    <!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO Premium plugin v15.9.1 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
    <title>Apple Salad with Candied Walnuts and Cranberries | RecipeTin Eats</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This Apple Salad is a celebration of textures and flavours! Crispy juicy apple, leafy salad, candied walnuts, plumped cranberries with a vinaigrette."/>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.recipetineats.com/apple-salad-candied-walnuts-cranberries/"/>
    <meta name="twitter:label1" content="Written by">
    <meta name="twitter:data1" content="Nagi">
    <meta name="twitter:label2" content="Est. reading time">
    <meta name="twitter:data2" content="5 minutes">
    <script type="application/ld+json" class="yoast-schema-graph">{ ... }</script>
```

And the parsed document.text returns for the same section for the document:

```
(function(w, d) {
    w.adthrive = w.adthrive || {};
    w.adthrive.cmd = w.adthrive.cmd || [];
    w.adthrive.plugin = 'adthrive-ads-1.0.43';
    w.adthrive.host = 'ads.adthrive.com';

    var s = d.createElement('script');
    s.async = true;
    s.referrerpolicy='no-referrer-when-downgrade';
    s.src = 'https://' + w.adthrive.host + '/sites/55cb7e3b4bc841bd0c4ea577/ads.min.js?referrer=' + w.encodeURIComponent(w.location.href);
    var n = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n);
})(window, document);


    
    Apple Salad with Candied Walnuts and Cranberries | RecipeTin Eats
    
    
    
    
    
    
    { ... }
```

`...` is what I want to extract, but with the nodes gone I cannot call on this block. I've abbreviated it for clarity of this post.

Has anyone else experienced this with only *some* websites when using Kanna? The above swift code works fine with 9 out of 10 websites.